# ¿Cuál es el origen del dicho "Éramos pocos y parió la abuela"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Quisiera encontrar la referencia de dónde proviene esta expresión.

Una vez estuve en Burgos (Castilla y León - España), y en el Monasterio de las Huelgas de Burgos, el guía nos comentó que esta expresión provenía por parte de una reina¿?, creo recordar, la cual tuvo un montón de hijos, y cuando su 'creo' hijo tambien tuvo hijos y demás, ella misma a una edad ya longeva para su época, tuvo otro hijo/hija, de ahí la expresión "Éramos pocos y parió la abuela".

Pero no consigo encontrar la cita ni la referencia a dicha mujer con la historia completa.

Si alguno tiene idea o tiene algún registro de que proceda de otro sitio me gustaría conocerlo.

Comment: Es: Éramos **muchos** y parió la abuela.....no pocos.

Comment: @Lambie segun los datos que encontré y por mi ciudad y varias donde he vivido, siempre ha sido pocos. Tiene sentido irónico a mi parecer y es como mejor se entiende. Si tienes algun dato oficial donde diga lo que comentas agradecería que lo compartieras.

Comment: Instituto Cervantes: https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58752&Lng=0

Comment: @Lambie En el enlace que has pasado, lo dicen como _pocos_ también, vamos que me estas dando la razón?

Comment: Ni en las variantes de tu enlace mencionan el _muchos_ , no creo que tenga nada que ver la verdad.

Comment: Es verdad. Solo ahora me di cuenta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo he encontrado, esta [página](https://archmunburgos.blogspot.com/2015/01/alfonso-viii-el-rey-burgales-parte-ii.html) hace refencia al archivo municipal de Burgos y cuenta lo que comentaba:

> Alfonso consiguió una tregua con los musulmanes que duró hasta 1210 y
>   las mediaciones de la reina hicieron que el conflicto con León
>   terminase gracias a la boda de su primogénita doña Berenguela con el
>   rey Alfonso IX de León en 1197. Matrimonio que duró hasta que el papa
>   Inocencio III lo disolvió en 1204 por razones de consanguinidad.
>   Berenguela regresó junto a sus hijos a la corte de sus padres en
>   Castilla, ese mismo año su madre dio a luz a su último hijo, Enrique I
>   a los 44 años.
>
> ```
> “Por si éramos pocos parió la abuela”
> ```

Si alguien encuentra alguna otra referencia anterior me gustaría conocerla.

Comment: Es interesante la referencia, el problema que tiene es que, aunque los datos que cita son correctos (Leonor Plantagenet, madre de Berenguela, dio a luz a los 44 años a Enrique I de Castilla), la cita de "éramos pocos y parió la abuela" no indica fuente alguna. He estado buscando en el CORDE y de momento la cita más antigua que he encontrado es de un libro de refranes de 1549, escrito por Pedro Vallés, en la siguiente forma: "Eramos trenta: y pario mi abuela." La forma "parió la abuela" parece más reciente, mientras que "parió mi abuela" es más antigua, de ahí mi duda con la cita.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon @Charlie , estuve buscando alguna cita oficial pero no encontré nada, pero te diré que varios historiadores de la ciudad lo utilizan como referencia (puede que mal documentada), pero parece ser cierta.
Si alguien encuentra más documentos me gustaría saberlo.